Best way to clean tarnish off small brass parts?
I just bought a bunch of fork connectors with DuPont crimps. They’re quite old and tarnished:


Is it necessary to clean them before crimping them?
What’s the best way to clean (and dry) them?

I don’t have access to industrial chemicals and fume hoods and the like, but I do have an ultrasonic cleaner and common household chemicals like 95% ethanol, 70% Isopropyl alcohol, methylated spirits, Goo Gone and Brasso. But I’d prefer to not hand-polish all of them with Brasso and a tiny cloth :-).

Have you tried muriatic acid (HCl?) It is very fast and thorough. Just be sure to flush with water quickly after.

Surely not worthy of an answer, but ho about a toothbrush? Or an electrical toothbrush? With any chemical you mentioned? Since acid was mentioned, what about vinegar?

@periblepsis I haven’t tried anything yet, and don’t have HCl on hand.

@Justme I specifically didn’t want to have to handle and policy each piece individually, that would be overly laborious.

Vinegar cleans brass. Some recipes use vinegar, baking soda (seems like the baking soda would knock the goodness out of the vinegar), & salt. I just use vinegar in an ultrasonic cleaner. Ketchup is purported to work.

Those don't look too bad imo.

Crimping and bolting will cut thru the patine with abrasion. Are you sure it is necessary? Then you need a gas tight fitting. Have you tested it with 1Amp for < 10mV drop?

@RobertAtkins In the US, you can pick it up at Home Depot. It is what we used in my chem lab days. And it is what i used to clean up many antique brass items, including some beautiful old street gas lamps restored from the late 1800s, with intricate scroll work. A lot of oxidation in a century of time. But it must be tested, first. Just a suggestion to consider.

Sugar free cola (phosphoric + citric acid) for  5-10min, then clean water rinse, and dry at about 50c in a fan oven or hair dryer.
I've used this a number of times with copper and brass parts, and it works a treat.

I had wondered if the phosphoric acid in Coke might be a good idea, that would be very straightforward if at least a couple of others can verify they’ve done something similar and it works?

Good call on the hair dryer too.

Just in case someone was thinking of trying: drinking the coke afterwards is not recommended. While brass might be food-safe, the tarnish probably isn't.

Need to get rid of the oxide layer, try de-oxit (or any other contact cleaner) which is a oxide remover for metals (works great for soldering irons or contacts).
I'd rinse them with Isopropyl alcohol and then a contact cleaner.

I think "contact cleaner" is the keyword here indeed. Available as spray so it is easy to apply.

You could make up a pickle solution, either something like citric acid or (better) mix up a commercial powder such as Krohn's Sparex #2 which is supposed to reduce pitting. Using "pickle" as a search term will give you all kinds of options, DIY and otherwise.
It's also a common process for folks who reload ammo- to get those brass cartridges all nice and shiny- and suppliers such as Hornady have proprietary cleaning solutions for use in ultrasonic cleaners. Some use tumblers or vibratory cleaners.
This is all assuming the parts are solid brass.
